# What good way for structure of project and owners of dirs in django?

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu

Imagine that my django project contain few apps. On server it located at `/var/www/ProjectName` dir. My username is Foo and sometimes i want edit file of server. Which best solution for next questions?

1. What owner of `/var/www`?
2. What owner of `/var/www/ProjectName`?
3. What apache process owner?
4. Where locate static files (css, js)? Is it from all apps in one dir or different dirs for different apps? What Owner of this dir?
5. Where locate media files (with upload users)? Is it from all apps in one dir or different dirs for different apps? What Owner of this dir?
6. What owner of py and pyc files, dirs of apps?

PS. Maybe project is located at my home directory?

I have some suggestions about that, but I would like to hear more experienced people.

Answer (score 2):

1. on ubuntu 12.04 `root` 
   `drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Nov  8 11:59 www`
2. `cd /var/www && ls -la` to see owner, probably root?
3. `www-data`, on 12.04 `www-data` homes directory is `/var/www` (`www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www`)
4. you can `collectstatic` to whatever directory you want in your project.  I often have a directory called `static` next to `manage.py`.  The owner is probably the same as the owner of your django project.  You only need to allow read access to this folder for apache
5. You will probably want to consider a centralized `media` folder, instead of having media for each app.  For both static and media you can fairly easily upload everything to s3 using `django-storages`
6. the owner can be anyone you want, I can't say the owner because it is your machine.  But, I think, the webserver will need to execute the `py` files, so you can change your permissions to allow for this.

You can locate the project whereever you want.  In apache virtual host you give the location of your `wsgi` file.  There is no reason your project must live in `/var/www`

Comment: 2. what good praktik for it? Someone recommend use www-data for owner this dir, but i think it's bad idea. 6. pyc files created www-data and  may changes from it. Is this normal? and i'm paranoiac

Answer (score 1):

Here is the structure I'm using.

```
django/
├── project_virtualenv                       (virtualenv folder)
└── versioned                                (folder for things that are versioned)
    ├── devdoc                               (documentation)
    └── py                                   (code)
        └── project                          (django project)
            ├── django_app                   (django app)
            │   
            ├── project                      (project folder)                  
                ├── files                    
                │   ├── media                (media, user uploads, etc)
                │   ├── production_static    (statics for production)
                │   └── static               (statics for development)
                └── templates
```

The directory django is located in the home directory on the production server, only the `wsgi.py` is in the publicly available folder (in my case `/home/user/public_html/wsgi`.

I've `chmod`ed everything in the Django folder to 777 just to get everything working on the testing production server. Not sure what are the security risks, even dough the files aren't directly served.